# How to make a created JSON object an groovy object, so that I cat access properties via dot(.) operator

Tags: grails, groovy, jsonbuilder

I created a JSON object via JSONBuilder class:

```
def json = new JSONBuilder().build {...}
```

How can I transform this JSON object to groovy object, so that I can access json properties via dot('.') operator?
JSON object has a field - target.
And I can access properties:

```
target.someProperty
```

But target property is protected.
Is there any other way to access json properties?

P.S.
Currently I use work around:

```
new JsonSlurper().parseText(json.toString())
```

It works, but I want something simplier.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSON.parse(json.toString()) as JSONObject

    println jsonObject.validproperty

    MyObject myObject = new MyObject(properties:jsonObject.properties)
```

This is largely dependent (obviously) on what the mapping is between your JSONObject and MyObject, but it should work.